# Como descobrir o valor a partir de saldos acumulados

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

No meu **SQL Server**, tenho uma **tabela** que contém o **registro** dos **odômetros** dos **veículos** com o **valor** final de cada **mês**.

Eu preciso saber qual o **valor** que **cada veículo** percorreu **mensalmente** com base nesses **saldos/valores**.

Detalhe é que pode haver meses **sem registros** quando o veículo ficou parado o mês inteiro, então tenho que ter o **registro com valor 0** naquele mês.

> **Layout da**  <kbd>**`Tabela: Registros`**</kbd>
>
> | **Campos** |

```
Placa_Veiculo (string)
AnoMes (AAAA/MM)
KM_fim_Mes (numerico)
```

> Se tabela eu tiver os seguintes dados:

```
placa=a, 
ano_mes=2019/01, 
km=660; 

placa = a, 
ano_mes=2019/03, 
km=700; 

placa=a, 
ano_mes=2019/04, 
km=780.
```

> O meu **select** tem que trazer **4 linhas** assim:

```
placa=a, ano_mes=2019/01, km=660;
placa=a, ano_mes=2019/02, km=0; 
placa=a, ano_mes=2019/03, km=40; 
placa=a, ano_mes=2019/04, km=80
```

Comment: Só existe a tabela `Registros`?

Comment: Para o veículo "a", para o mês "2019/01" não há como calcular quantos quilômetros percorreu pois não se tem a informação anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Eis solução que trata a possibilidade de carros terem o registro em períodos diferentes.

```
-- código #1
with 
Registros_0 as (
SELECT Placa_Veiculo as placa, 
       min (AnoMes) as ano_mes_inicial, 
       max (AnoMes) as ano_mes_final
  from Registros
  group by Placa_Veiculo
),
Registros_1 as (
SELECT R0.placa, R0.ano_mes_inicial as ano_mes, R.KM_fim_Mes as km,
       convert (date, R0.ano_mes_inicial + '/01', 111) as AnoMes,
       convert (date, R0.ano_mes_final + '/01', 111) as AnoMes_F
  from Registros_0 as R0 
       inner join Registros as R on R.Placa_Veiculo = R0.placa 
                                    and R.AnoMes = R0.ano_mes_inicial
union all
SELECT R1.placa, 
       convert (char(7), dateadd (month, +1, R1.AnoMes), 111),
       coalesce ((SELECT R.KM_fim_Mes 
                    from Registros as R
                    where R.Placa_Veiculo = R1.placa      
                          and R.AnoMes = convert (char(7), dateadd (month, +1, R1.AnoMes), 111)),
                 R1.km),
       dateadd (month, +1, R1.AnoMes),
       R1.AnoMes_F
  from Registros_1 as R1 
  where dateadd (month, +1, R1.AnoMes) <= R1.AnoMes_F                           
)
SELECT placa, ano_mes, km,
       case when km >= lag (km) over(partition by placa order by ano_mes)
                 then (km - lag (km) over(partition by placa order by ano_mes)) 
            else NULL end as Percorrido    
  from Registros_1;
```

Registros_0: obtém, para cada veículo, qual é o primeiro e o último registro

Registros_1: monta, mês a mês para cada veículo, qual o valor de quilometragem. Utiliza CTE recursiva.

---

Outra possibilidade é utilizar algoritmos de *gaps and islands* para preencher as lacunas e então calcular as distâncias percorridas por veículo/mês.

Answer (score -1):

Tente executar esse script:

```
SELECT Placa_Veiculo, AnoMes, SUM(KM_fim_Mes)
FROM Registros
GROUP BY AnoMes
```

Comment: oi, agradeço mas preciso de um script bem trabalhado que faça cálculos para chegar no resultado que eu coloquei no exemplo

Comment: Não seria mais fácil retornar somente os meses que contém valores no mês, e na linguagem que você está utilizando (PHP, JAVA ...) efetuar a verificação dos meses faltantes (sem valores)?